# typo3 file saving from backen with dynamic path

Tags: dynamic, file-upload, upload, typo3

I have to save some posts with images. i create a directory for each post and save images there, but in backend if i edit/save the post the relation between images and post dies, any ideea how can i configure the saving path for the backend?
thanks anticipated.

Comment: your question is not 100% clear... please feed us with code and some more information. what do you mean with "posts". are you using an extension?

Comment: hi. thank you for answering. users are making posts... completing their name, mail, add a text description, post title and upload images. i'm using extensions to save, list and display these posts. in extensions i have an upload folder setted in TS. (uploads/"extkey"). while saving the images i have to create a folder for each post (uploads/extkey/post_title), but when i edit the post in BE the relation between the post and images dies because BE dosn't know about the subdir so he can't acces the files and trys to save them in uploads/"extkey"... can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you forgot to set the directory also in file: ext_emconf.php
its not done when only creating the dir in the extension itself. this maybe is your (or typo3) problem

go into file: ext_emconf.php: and edit the array 'createDirs' => '

Comment: the dir is created. my problem is than i can't "tell" for the BE that images for post X are in the subfolder Y (subfolder is created with the extension in php)... so the BE "thinks" that the source folder is the parent folder (folder setted in TS)

Comment: ok i see... i found a question via goodle where they are creating dynamic files you can adept that maybe for your folders problem too. go over thees snippets inside: http://old.nabble.com/Dynamic-path-in-$TCA-td22739275.html

Comment: would be nice to implement some code for other users becouse it seems information for this problem is quiet rare on www. use keywords like "dynamic, extension, upload, folder" by editing your question or posting an answer on your own here and accept it

Comment: @ggzone ups the Link is broken. :/